# Why does the energy difference of a reversible process not equal that of an irreversible process in an adiabatic expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose that one mole of an ideal gas at $P_1$ and $V_1$ adiabatically expands to $P_2$ and $V_2$, reversibly and irreversibly (two separate processes). Since $\Delta U$ is a state function, why is it wrong to say that $\Delta U_{rev} = \Delta U_{irrev}$? (Since in an adiabatic process, there is no heat transfer, we know that $\Delta U = w$)?

Comment: Related: [Reversible and Irreversible adiabatic expansion](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/38127/7951)

Comment: I can't answer this question but I still want to nitpick (how typical of me). $U$ is the state function, not $\Delta U$.

Comment: Both $U$ and $\Delta U$ are state functions.

Comment: A state function is a property of a system. $U$ is a property of a system, and $\Delta U$ is, loosely speaking, a "property" of a process that said system undergoes.

Comment: Please do not use MathJax for question titles due to searching issues. Also welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to find out more about it.

Comment: But $\Delta U$ is defined in terms of state functions so it itself is also a state function....at least from what I recall

Comment: The correct application of that phrase is: $H$ is a state function because $H = U + pV$ and $U$, $p$ and $V$ are all state functions. $\Delta U$ with the $\Delta$ is **not** a state function. A **state** function is something that only depends on the current **state** of a system. $\Delta U$ depends on a process, defined by **two states** of a system, the initial and final.

Comment: @orthocresol [Here](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Thermodynamics/State_Functions) state functions are defined as "a property whose value does not depend on the path taken to reach that specific value" which is the definition I am familiar with. This would imply that as `notorious` said $\Delta U$ is indeed a state function.

Comment: @Philipp I learnt, and I've only seen, the specific phrasing: "$U$ is a state function" $\Leftrightarrow$ "$\Delta U$ is independent of the path taken". The way I interpret the phrase "state function" is that it is a function of a state: $f = f(p,V,T)$. But $\Delta U$ is a function of *two* states: $\Delta U = \Delta U(p_1,V_1,T_1,p_2,V_2,T_2)$ (generally speaking). Analogously a path function is a function of a path (i.e. a line integral). But that's just my own interpretation, which is just my attempt to be logically consistent with what I was taught, so I might very well be wrong.

Comment: @orthocresol I understand your point of view and am not perfectly sure about the actual definition. So I am not able to say who is right or wrong. All I remember from my thermodynamics courses is that we treated the "$\Delta$-versions" of the thermodynamic potentials the same way we did the potentials themselves, i.e. treated them like state functions (e.g. used Maxwell relations and such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the premise of the question itself is false: if you start with a given state (P1, V1) and undergo a reversible, adiabatic (hence isentropic) expansion, you can get to state P2, V2. But if you don't have the requirement of reversibility, I don't think it is possible to gain the same second state - there will be either internal heating/cooling, causing the expected final volume (or pressure, depending on the mechanism of expansion) to not be P2 or V2.