# How to calculate the final temperature of a gas when it undergoes adiabatic expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory-of-gases

The question is as follows:

> A sample of $\pu{4.0 moles}$ of a gas ($C_{v,m} = \pu{21 J mol-1 K-1}$) has an initial pressure of $\pu{304.4 kPa}$ and an initial volume of $\pu{20 dm3}$ at $\pu{270 K}$. It undergoes an adiabatic expansion against a constant external pressure of $\pu{79.8 kPa}$, until the volume has increased by a factor of $3$. Calculate the final temperature.

I have calculated:  $Q = 0$  and $w = \pu{-3192 J}$ and change in internal energy $=\Delta U = \pu{-31922 J}$.

The next question is to calculate the final temperature of the gas. However, I am unsure on how to calculate this. Originally I thought as $Q=0$, then the final temperature would be the same as the initial temperature. However, I have realized this is incorrect.

Comment: What is the relationship between change in internal energy and change in temperature for an ideal gas?

Answer (score 6):

Rather than answer the question numerically I have outlined the four different cases, *reversible / irreversible* and *isothermal / adiabatic*.

In adiabatic changes no energy is transferred to the system, that is the heat absorbed or released to the surroundings is zero. A vacuum (Dewar) flask realises a good approximation to an adiabatic container. Any work done must therefore be at the expense of the internal energy. If the ‘system’ is a gas then  its temperature will not remain constant during any expansion or compression.

In expansion the work done is $dw=-pdV$ and the change in internal energy $ dU=C_vdT$.

The heat change is zero then $dq=0$ which means from the First Law 
$$dU = dw$$
and so
$$ C_vdT = -pdV$$

Dividing both sides by *T* and for one mole of an perfect gas $p=RT/V$ thus 
$$C_v\frac{dT}{T}=-R\frac{dV}{V}$$
If the gas starts at $T_1,V_1$ and ends up at $T_2,V_2$ the last equation can be integrated (and rearranged) to give
$$\ln\left (\frac{T_2}{T_1}\right)=-\ln\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)^{R/C_v}$$
or 
$$\frac{T_1}{T_2}=+\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)^{R/C_v}$$

using the relationship $C_p = C_v+R$
$$\frac{T_1}{T_2}=+\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)^{(C_p-C_v)/C_v}$$
Using the gas law this van be rewritten in a more useful form as
$$ p_1V_1^{\gamma } = p_2V_2^{\gamma }$$
where $\gamma = C_p/C_v$. This is also written as $pV^\gamma = const$.

The change in internal energy in an adiabatic process is
$$\Delta U=C_v(T_2-T_1)$$

*Adiabatic reversible*

In a *reversible adiabatic* change we use the formulas above to work out what happens. If *n* moles of a gas fill a container of volume $V_1$ at $p_1$ atm. and is expanded reversibly and adiabatically until it is in equilibrium at a final pressure $p_2$ we can calculate the final volume and temperature. The values of $C_p$ and $C_v$ are assumed to be known and are constant with temperature.

The equation to use is
$$ p_1V_1^{\gamma} = p_2V_2^{\gamma}$$
and as only $V_2$ is unknown this can be calculated.  The work done is 
$$w=nC_v(T_2-T_1)$$

*Adiabatic irreversible*

In an *irreversible adiabatic* change if *n* moles of an perfect gas expands irreversibly from a pressure of $p_1$ against a constant external pressure $p_2$ the temperature drops from $T_1$ to $T_2$. We can calculate how much work is done and the final volume.
The internal energy change is $\Delta U= nC_v(T_2-T_1)$
and the work done is $w=p(V_2-V_1)$ and as $\Delta U = w$ (as the system is adiabatic) the final volume can be obtained.  Similarly if the volumes are known the final temperature can be obtained.

*Isothermal irreversible*

In an *isothermal irreversible* change the work done on *suddenly* allowing a perfect gas to expanding from $V_1$ to $V_2$ is determined by the final external pressure $p_2$ and is 
$$ q=-w =\int_{V_1}^{V_2} pdV = p_2(V_2-V_1)$$
thus expansion into a vacuum does no work.

*Isothermal reversible*

A *reversible isothermal* change performs the maximum possible amount of work, and assuming a perfect gas,
$$ q=-w_{rev} =\int_{V_1}^{V_2} pdV=nRT \int_{V_1}^{V_2} \frac{1}{V}dV$$

$$w_{rev} =- nRT\ln\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)= - nRT\ln\left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Work done in adiabatic process $W =\frac {nR \Delta T}{1-\gamma}$

$Cv$ (specific heat at constant volume) $= 21 \frac{\mathrm{J}}{\mathrm{mol}*\mathrm{K}}$

$Cv = \frac{fR}{2}  \to f = \frac{21\times2}{8.314}= 5$
So $\gamma= \frac{f+2}{f}$, where $f$ is the degree of freedom.

$\to γ = \frac7 5$

Now work done at constant pressure $= 79.8\times(1000)\times[60(10^{-3}) - 20(10^{13})] = 3192 \,\mathrm{J}$ (positive work done by gas. The internal pressure will simultaneously be equal to the external pressure otherwise first law of thermodynamics won't hold true.)

$W = \frac{nR ΔT}{1-γ}$

$3192 = \frac{4(8.316)(T - 270)}{1-\frac{7}{5}}$

$T = [\frac{3192(-0.4)}{4(8.316)}] + 270$

$\to T = 231.61 K$